# Problems accessing property

Tags: c#, list, properties

With the help of everyone in a very short time. The problem got solved by overriding the toString Method.

I have a problem with the following: (solved)

```
public class CryptoApiResponse
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "ticker")]
    public List<CryptoAttributes> CryptoCurrency { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Currency:{CryptoCurrency[0].Currency} " +
               $"PriceFiat:{CryptoCurrency[0].PriceFiat} " +
               $"Fiat:{CryptoCurrency[0].TargetFiat}";
    }
}

public class CryptoAttributes
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "base")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "target")]
    public string TargetFiat { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "price")]
    public string PriceFiat { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to access the following:

```
public void Display<CryptoApiResponse>(List<CryptoApiResponse> apiList)
{
    if (apiList != null)
    {
        foreach (CryptoApiResponse cryptoCurrency in apiList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cryptoCurrency.ToString());
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You can't call `ticker.Ticker` because it represents a _list_ of `Base`. You need to access its items.

Comment: Your variable names suck.

Comment: @SamAxe not only variables...

Comment: @SamAxe I using same naming api uses: https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/xem-usd

Comment: Don't use 'var' is is confusing.  Try : foreach (Base ticker in crypto)

Comment: @jdweng you are right thanks for the tipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(obj);
// this means more or less the following
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
// this means you should override the ToString() method
// or to make a custom string
```

You're iterating through a List, and in each crypto there exist a sub-list List. In short you get List>.

When you foreach this List, you may need to use a second foreach to iterate the values in the Sub list to reach your property.

```
foreach (var crypt in crypto)
{
  foreach (var basedata in crypt.Ticker)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Currency:{basedata.Currency} Price: {basedata.Price} Target: {basedata.Target}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the naming of the API you linked and differentiate between lists ans single objects names it will be easier to understand what is the problem. The classes should look something like this (pay attention to the difference between `Ticker` and `Tickers`

```
public class Crypto
{
    public List<Ticker> Tickers { get; set; }
}

public class Ticker
{
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

The parameter `crypto` (should be `cryptos`) in `Display` is a list and `Tickers` is a list, so you need nested loop. You should also remove the `Crypto` parameter from the methos signature as it hides the `Crypto` class

```
public void Display(List<Crypto> cryptos)
{
    foreach (Crypto crypto in cryptos)
    {
        foreach (Ticker ticker in crypto.Tickers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ticker);
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you would like to use partial Linq

```
public void Display(List<Crypto> cryptos)
{
    foreach (Ticker ticker in cryptos.SelectMany(crypto => crypto.Tickers))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ticker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use "Crypto" instead of "var" when looping? I mean do it like this. I remeber the version before VS2015 (may be VS2010), the type of variable will be treated as object if we use "var".

```
public void Display<Crypto>(List<Crypto> crypto)
{
    if (crypto != null)
    {
        // Currency, Target and Price
        foreach (***Crypto*** ticker in crypto)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ticker); // ticker Type Crypo
            // ticker.Ticker
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```